# Tab Item with a Close control

Tags: eclipse-rcp

In my eclipse plugin, at runtime i create multiple TabItems for a Tabfolder based upon the user interaction. The problem arises when too many TabItems are created. I was looking for an option to create a TabItem with a close control so that the user can close the corresponding TabItem when not necessary. Is there a way to create this?

Answer (score 3):

If you use CTabFolder instead of TabFolder then you can use CTabItem for the tabs and pass the SWT.CLOSE style into the constructor. That will create a close button on the tab.

Answer (score 0):

> press <kbd>SHIFT + TAB</kbd>  to switch between Editor at time
>   one editor open.

you press <kbd>SHIFT + TAB</kbd>  key second  time to open
another editor but close previous editor using RCP Eclipse.

```
public class Emp_editor_open extends AbstractHandler{

    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {

        IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(event);
        IWorkbenchPage page = window.getActivePage();

        //Three object create in EditorInput 
        ProductEditorInput product_input=new ProductEditorInput();
        EmployeeEditorInput emp_input=new EmployeeEditorInput();
        UserEditorInput std_input = new UserEditorInput();

        IEditorReference[] editors = page.getEditorReferences();
        System.out.println("Length : "+editors.length);

        if(editors.length==0){
            //First Time or empty editors to check this condition
            try {
                page.openEditor(product_input,ProductEditor.ID);
                System.out.println("product Editor open");
            } catch (PartInitException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        else if(page.getActiveEditor().getTitle().equals("Product_Editor")){
            System.out.println("Product:: "+page.getActiveEditor().getTitle());
            try {
                page.closeAllEditors(true);
                page.openEditor(emp_input, EmployeeEditor.Id);
                System.out.println("Employee Editor open");
            } catch (PartInitException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else if(page.getActiveEditor().getTitle().equals("Employee_Editor")){
            System.out.println("Emp:: "+page.getActiveEditor().getTitle());
            try {
                page.closeAllEditors(true);
                page.openEditor(std_input, UserEditor.ID);
                System.out.println("student Editor open");
            } catch (PartInitException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else if(page.getActiveEditor().getTitle().equals("Student_Editor")){
            System.out.println("Product:: "+page.getActiveEditor().getTitle());
            try {
                page.closeAllEditors(true);
                page.openEditor(product_input,ProductEditor.ID);
                System.out.println("product Editor open");
            } catch (PartInitException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else {
            try {
                page.closeAllEditors(true);
                page.openEditor(product_input,ProductEditor.ID);
                System.out.println("product Editor open");
            } catch (PartInitException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Plugin.xml

---

```
    <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
        <command
                defaultHandler="rcp_demo.Toolbar.Emp_editor_open"
                id="RCP_Demo.Toolbar.emp_editor_open_cmd"
                name="Employee_Editor_open">
        </command>
    </extension>
    <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
        <key
                commandId="RCP_Demo.Toolbar.emp_editor_open_cmd"
                schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"
                sequence="M2+TAB">
        </key>              
    </extension>
```

Key sequence : M2 means <kbd>Shift</kbd>